# GWT validation framework internationalization for messages in annotations

Tags: gwt, internationalization, gwt-validation

After having read [this page](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/wiki/GWT_INTERNATIONALIZATION) I found a way of internationalizing validation messages. It is done by placing translations of each error type into `ValidationMessages.properties` files.

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=The property must be between {min} and {max}
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=The property must not be null
```

It is error type-specific and it's not what I need in my app. I need a unique message for each of my fields in validated beans. With no internationalization it can be done using annotations.

```
@Pattern(regexp = UiLogicUtils.EMAIL_REGEX, message = "Email is invalid.")
private String requesterEmail;
```

So how can I make translations of the "Email is invalid" text just for this specific field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the answer, because I have not used @Pattern, but in the docs, it says that the message field of the @Pattern is not a text, but a key into the messages file. Look here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html#message()

By default message="{javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}" which looks like a valid key in ValidationMessages.properties file. I suppose you only have to specify a custom key and use it.