# GWT validation framework internationalization, wrong code page

Tags: gwt, internationalization, codepages, gwt-validation

This one is related to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019777/gwt-validation-framework-internationalization-for-messages-in-annotations/14021487#14021487). My problem is that after I put messages in `ValidationMessages.properties` in languages other than English (Ukrainian and Czech in my case) I got messed up characters in the end. The encoding of all those `ValidationMessages.properties` files in the bundle is UTF-8, the same as I use for the other translations, and those work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly solved the problem, but as I moved from the GWT Validation to the Hibernate Validation libraries it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when reading UTF-8 properties files server-side using the ResourceBundle class. Java assumes that properties files are ISO-8859-1, while GWT assumes they are UTF-8. Oddly enough, there is no "one liner" way to tell java to read it as UTF-8. I ended up implementing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle) for reading it server-side and it works well for me, despite it not being as simple as one would hope.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look on the Hibernate Validation library and its contents I noticed that there are default translations for languages like Czech and Hungarian and they use JavaScript Unicode notation (like `\u0000`) for special characters. Looks ugly but works.