# GWT validation framework, how to specify location of internationalization bundle

Tags: gwt, internationalization, gwt-validation

This one is related to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019777/gwt-validation-framework-internationalization-for-messages-in-annotations/14021487#14021487). Is it possible in GWT validation framework to specify location of `ValidationMessages.properties` files and their names? I already have messages translations in my application and I'd prefer them to be in one location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom UserValidationMessagesResolver:

```
public class CustomValidationMessagesResolver extends AbstractValidationMessageResolver implements UserValidationMessagesResolver {
    protected CustomValidationMessagesResolver() {
        super((ConstantsWithLookup) GWT.create(ValidationConstants.class));
    }
}
```

In the above code, ValidationConstants is the class resulting from running I18NSync on my properties file.

Then in *.gwt.xml:

```
<replace-with class="yourpackage.client.validation.CustomValidationMessagesResolver">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.validation.client.UserValidationMessagesResolver" />
</replace-with>
```

You can find a complete example [here](http://gglwebtoolkit.blogspot.ca/2011_12_01_archive.html).